# Editor script: refer to selected ScriptableObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

Another way to phrase this question would be "Get ScriptableObject from selection in editor code".

I have a `public class DialogueObject : ScriptableObject` from which I create many SOs. I'd like to automate some actions around these SOs like populating data using editor script but I can't figure out or Google-Fu how to get a handle on them.

This does not work (`NullReferenceException`):

`DialogueObject obj = Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<DialogueObject>();`

So, how to select a ScriptableObject in the project window and edit it's data via editor scripting?

Update:
I discovered that taking it as a public variable and assigning it in the inspector works (`obj = (DialogueObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("DialogueObject", obj, typeof(DialogueObject));`), but I'd prefer to lift it from the `Selection` object instead, so still looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need a custom `EditorWindow`. And in this editor window we can use one of the Unity Editor Events which is `OnSelectionChange()`, by events I mean all the message methods which are called by the Unity itself ie. Awake, OnEnable, Start, Update, etc...

`OnSelectionChange()` will be called when ever you select an object, regardless of `Scene Hierarchy` or `Project View`. Now you just have to get a selected object using `Selection.activeObject;`. After getting the current selected object you can compare and cast it to your SO type. and can draw a custom editor based on your needs.

Below is an example of a such simple:

```
public class SoEditor : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/SoScript")] //To show an editor window...
    public static void ShowEditorWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<SoEditor>();
    }

    //This is one of the Unity message which is being called when ever the selection gets changed.
    public void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        var obj = Selection.activeObject; //Get the object/

        if (obj == null) //Check for the null.
            return;

        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(SoScript))
        {
            SoScript sos = obj as SoScript; //Here is your type casted object.

            ///Draw or populate your editor fields here...
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Make sure that you are using `Selection.activeObject` and not `Selection.activeGameObject` Otherwise you will get a Null Exception if the selected object is not a `GameObject`.

Hope this gets you to your solution...✌️

Referances:
[EditorWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html)
[EditorWindow.OnSelectionChange()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnSelectionChange.html)

Comment: Yep, that was the issue (`activeGameObject`), thanks. `obj = Selection.activeObject as DialogueObject;` works.

Answer (score 0):

`Selection.activeGameObject` indeed refers to a `GameObject`! A `ScriptableObject` is also not a component but rather its own asset base type.

You should simply use [`Selection.activeObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-activeObject.html) combined with a type check like e.g.

```
if(Selection.activeObject is DialogueObject obj)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

There is actually also no need for an `EditorWindow` in specific.

You can rather simply directly subscribe to [`Selection.selectionChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-selectionChanged.html).

Comment: I really did not knew about ```selectionChange``` callback. That's very helpful. thanks.